# GeoRegionValuePlot optimization

Tags: performance-tuning, geographics, entity, interpreter

I have the following piece of code that plots a colormap by zipcode.

Zips is an array of zip codes (All in the US mainland) and testscore is just some made up data for testing purposes.

The list of usable zipcodes can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FoJ9_n7BjL6jITo38voRIvKp7KW7b1va) or [here](https://pastebin.com/9EjYT1iM).

```
zips = ToString /@ zips;
zipcheck[x_] := If[StringLength[x] < 5, StringJoin["0", x], x];
zips = zipcheck /@ zips;
entmaker[x_] := Entity["ZIPCode", ToString[x]];
entzip = entmaker /@ zips;
n = Dimensions[zips][[1]]
testscore = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
GeoRegionValuePlot[Rule @@@ Transpose[{entzip, testscore}],ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors",MissingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1.0], White, EdgeForm[Dashed]],ColorFunctionScaling -> True, PlotStyle -> Opacity[1.],PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic]]
```

So far the plot takes about 30 min to produce a plot. Any ideas on how to speed up the code?

Comment: The slow part is likely the conversion of the ZIP codes to regions that can be processed by `GeoRegionValuePlot[]`; separate that out from the plotting.

Comment: How can I force the data to be processed without being plotted?

Comment: Perhaps something like `EntityValue[#, EntityProperty["ZIPCode", "Polygon"]] & /@ entzip`.

Comment: I see, then pass that with "testscore" into the GeoRegionValuePlot[]

Comment: Indeed. $\phantom{}$

Comment: `EntityValue[entzip, "Polygon"]` should be faster than mapping. 1 API call vs many.